# Cannot sample CPU using VisualVM

Tags: java, visualvm

Does it work on a Mac?
I want to make a CPU sample of a jar on VisualVM for Mac, but it doesn't enable the CPU button.
I can successfully sample the same jar on Windows 7.

CPU settings are all disabled too.

In the summary, it keeps displaying the same message:
"CPU sampling:
Checking availability..."

I have no clue. Do I have to enable something?

using:
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334)

Comment: Yes, VisualVM works on Mac OS X. Which version of java is used for your java application? Can VisualVM CPU sample itself?

Comment: I've seen this problem a couple of times on different OSes, usually restarting visualvm will solve the issue.  No idea why though